# Is it possible to deploy PaLM on my own cloud environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, palm

Is it possible to deploy PaLM entirely on my own (GCP) cloud environment (hence ensuring no sensitive data leaves my environment) ? If not, is such deployment pattern on the roadmap ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, the foundation models are deployed once by google and managed centrally by Google. So, you can't have access to those model and deploy them on your own project (on GCP or elsewhere).

However, as any services, Google Cloud guaranty the data privacy by default. Take the Cloud Storage or BigQuery, you never asked to have an instance in your project! You use a SaaS solution, managed by google. And it works seamlessly!!

---

If you want to fine tune the foundation model, again, you won't retrain directly the BIG model. But you will create an intermediary layer that will be used by the foundation model to tune the generation. It's named "parameter efficient tuning". You can find more details here: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/models/tune-models

(and at 2 minutes in the video)

Comment: Thanks Guillaume! Can Google ensure at least the regionality of the service, i.e. ensure that sensitive would only be processed on a given zone i.e. `europe-west6` ?

Comment: Not sure at this very early stage of the product deployment. But at the end, even if I hadn't asked the dev team, I'm sure it will. As any AI product (DocumentAI, Speech, Vision,...)

Comment: Any update on this @guillaume blaquiere or google ?

Comment: There are more and more regions, but not all are deployed for now (for bisou@002, you have 4 regions in europe, but you don't have europe-west6 yet)